# While loop problem

Tags: programming

I have a simple code for bisection method that isn't working correctly. Can someone please tell me what is wrong.

```
 f[x_] := x*Log[x] + x^2;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
i = 1;
Subscript[a, i] = 0.4;
Subscript[b, i] = 0.6;
Subscript[error, i] = Abs[f[Subscript[x, i]]];
Subscript[error, i] = 1;
While[
 Subscript[error, i] >= 0.0001,
 Subscript[x, i] = (Subscript[a, i] + Subscript[b, i])/2;
 If[
   N@f[Subscript[x, i]] > 0, 
   Subscript[a, i + 1] == Subscript[a, i] && 
    Subscript[b, i + 1] ==  Subscript[x, i], 
   Subscript[a, i + 1] == Subscript[x, i] && 
    Subscript[b, i + 1] == Subscript[b, i]
   ]
  Print["iteration ", i , ", output", ": ", Subscript[x, i], ", ", 
   Subscript[a, i], ", ", Subscript[b, i]]
  i++
 ]
```

Comment: Avoid the subscripts, except for pretty-printing purposes. It just makes debugging harder to do.

Answer (score 2):

`Equal` (a.k.a. `==`) is a logical operation. You have to use `Set` (a.k.a. `=`) in order to assign values to variables. Moreover, `And` (a.k.a. `&&`) is a logical operation; use a semicolon `;` instead. This is the cleaned code, incoporating J.M.'s remark on `Subscript`.

```
f[x_] := x Log[x] + x^2;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
i = 1;
imax = 100;
ClearAll[a, b, x, error, c];
a[i] = 0.4;
b[i] = 0.6;
x[i] = b[i];
error[i] = Abs[f[x[i]]];
While[error[i] >= 0.0001 && i < imax,
 x[i + 1] = (a[i] + b[i])/2.;
 c = f[x[i + 1]];
 If[c > 0.,
  a[i + 1] = a[i]; b[i + 1] = x[i + 1],
  a[i + 1] = x[i + 1]; b[i + 1] = b[i]
  ];
 error[i + 1] = Abs[c];
 Print["iteration ", i, ", output", ": ", x[i], ", ", a[i], ", ", b[i]];
 i++;
 ]
```

**Remark**

Performancewise, it would be better to forget old iterates and simply reuse the variables, `a`, `b`, `x`, and `error`:

```
i = 1;
imax = 100;
ClearAll[a, b, x, error];
a = 0.4;
b = 0.6;
x = b;
error = Abs[f[x]];
While[error >= 0.0001 && i < imax,
 x = (a + b)/2.;
 c = f[x];
 If[c > 0.,
  a = a; b = x,
  a = x; b = b
  ];
 error = Abs[c];
 i++;
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome!